# Impala table from spark partitioned parquet files

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, impala, partition

I have generated some partitioned parquet data using Spark, and I'm wondering how to map it to an Impala table... Sadly, I haven't found any solution yet.

The schema of parquet is like :

```
{ key: long,
value: string,
date: long }
```

and I partitioned it with `key` and `date`, that gives me this kind of directories on my hdfs :

```
/data/key=1/date=20170101/files.parquet
/data/key=1/date=20170102/files.parquet
/data/key=2/date=20170101/files.parquet
/data/key=2/date=20170102/files.parquet
...
```

Do you know how I could tell Impala to create a table from this dataset with corresponding partitions (and without having to loop on each partition as I could have read) ? Is it possible ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try to change the perspective, i.e. create an EXTERNAL table with Impala, then use a Spark `hiveContext` to INSERT INTO that table, then simply run a REFRESH in Impala to acknowledge the new data files?

Comment: BTW, are you sure that your partitioning makes sense - how large are your Parquet files? And a `date` column can only bring trouble, since it's a reserved word in SQL...!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming by schema of parquet , you meant the schema of the dataset and then using the columns to partition , you will have only the key column in the actual `files.parquet` files . Now you can proceed as follows

The solution is to use an impala external table .

```
create external table mytable (key BIGINT) partitioned by (value String ,
date BIGINT) stored as parquet location '....../data/'
```

Note that in above statement , you have to give path till the data folder

```
alter table mytable recover partitions'

refresh mytable;
```

The above 2 commands will automatically detect the partitions based on the schema of the table and get to know about the parquet files present in the sub directories.

Now , you can start querying the data .

Hope it helps

Comment: Oh boy, thanks for the hint with `recover partitions`. Cloudera's docs stated _"The RECOVER PARTITIONS clause automatically recognizes any data files present in these new directories, **the same as the REFRESH statement does**."_ which was in my case a complete lie... Refresh table does not do the scan recover partitions does. +1